# How to get a tag if I know the property of data-ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vba, excel, angular-ngmodel

I ask for help in resolving the issue.

I have code with which I fill the field:

```
oie.document.parentWindow.execScript "angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[52]).scope().someText = '12345';"
oie.document.parentWindow.execScript "angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[52]).scope().$apply();"
```

In this case, I get the field using the tag number [52], but i know the property data-ng-model of the `input` tag that I fill - this property is called "sometext".

Can I fill out the form field by referring not to the tag number, but by the property `data-ng-model`?

Will it work like this:

```
oie.document.parentWindow.execScript "angular.element('[ng-model="sometext"]') = '12345';"
oie.document.parentWindow.execScript "angular.element('[ng-model="sometext"]').$apply();"
```

Comment: should work if you make sure you don't break the string

Comment: I I tried to use this code, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
oie.document.parentWindow.execScript "angular.element('[ng-model="sometext"]').scope().sometext = '12345';"
oie.document.parentWindow.execScript "angular.element('[ng-model="sometext"]').scope().$apply();"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly!

Comment: Initially, your code worked fine, but now there is an error:
`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-ng-model=sometext]`.Help me please. What could be the cause of the error?

Comment: Does it work without the `data-` prefix? Also shouldn't `sometext` be wrapped in quotes. You've to provide more context if I'm to answer your question properly without just saying it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

When I wrapped `some.text` in quotes,  I get a syntax error in the VBA editor window.  This code leads to error: `oie.document.parentWindow.execScript "angular.element('[data-ng-model=some.text]').scope().some.text = '12345';"
oie.document.parentWindow.execScript "angular.element('[data-ng-model=some.text]').scope().$apply();"`  But if the name of the property `data-ng-model` consists of a single word without dots, everything works fine. Help me please :(

Comment: Sorry, I can not put your voice, because it has not yet scored 15 votes :-( As soon as will type, I will put you to vote.